# How to ensure a generated config.h file is in the include path?

Tags: c, cmake, config, include-path

I use CMake to build a C project. Specifically, I use the following line:

```
configure_file(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

this works fine as long as I build in the source directory. However, if I build elsewhere, the `config.h` file is created in `/path/to/build/dir/config.h` rather than in the source directory - and that's not part of the include path. How can I have CMake...

- Ensure this specific file is included, or
- Have the C compiler look both under the original source dir and under the build dir for include files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an automatism for include directories with [`CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) in CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

> If this variable is enabled, CMake automatically adds `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to the include path for each directory.

So I prefer to individually have the following call on a need-by basis in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

**Edit**: Thanks for the hint of @zaufi, if your generated header file has a target scope then you should prefer (CMake >= Version 2.8.12) to make it only visible to that target (not globally to all targets) with:

```
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

*Note*: For source files with relative paths CMake looks in both directories `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

Comment: I used your second suggestion, since I actually need to put `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src"` in the include path.

Comment: use `target_include_directories(<target> PRIVATE ...)` instead of `include_directories`

Comment: @zaufi Thanks for the hint. Yes, if you are not generating a global config header you should prefer the `target_include_directories()` call. I've updated my answer accordingly.